# How to setup local database from remote database in visual studio asp.net project?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am working on an ASP.NET project which accessing a remote SQL Server database. My objective is to set up this remote database on my local system.

I have tried 2 ways, but I'm facing problems both ways:

**(1)** Using SQL Server import and export wizard.

I get an error saying that the connection state is closed, but I am able to fetch all database tables of remote database:

[image]

[image]

**(2)** Schema and Data comparison from SQL Server object explorer inside of Visual Studio.

Here I get an error in that database user-related issues are showing. User or group not found:

[image]

I have tried other things in the last 4 days also but not found any clue to solve it. I am new to ASP.NET and SQL. Please help. Any helpful answer will always be appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried the [Dennis1679's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58888653/6720479), but the following issues are coming.

> One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as of
>   a data package.    Error SQL71564:Error validating element[username]:
>   The element[username] has been orphaned from its login and cannot be
>   deployed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15), connect to the remote database, right-click on the database, choose export data-tier application. Then connect to your local instance and import data-tier application.

Connect to the remote database:

[image: Login]

Right-click on the database choose export data-tier application:

[image: Export data-tier]

- Follow the wizard and save the `.bacpac` somewhere
- Connect to your local SQL Server `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`
- Choose `Import data-tier application`
- Select the previously saved `.bacpac` and import it. Now your local instance should have the same database

[image: Import data-tier application]

Comment: this error is coming while exporting the database -  "One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as of a data package.
   Error SQL71564:Error validating element[username]: The element[username] has been orphaned from its login and cannot be deployed."

Comment: @AbhishekJoshi My answer will work for you, but you're now facing a different issue. Try to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15